# Ember Data: how can I delete/unload a record that's stuck in the "inFlight" state?

Tags: ajax, ember.js, ember-data

Say I am trying to save a Foo record to the back-end. For whatever reason, the back-end never returns (neither success nor failure).

From what I can see, it looks like foo stays in the "in flight" state. The problem with this state is it completely locks the record - you can't do anything on it (can't rollback, can't unload). I understand why it is like that (to try and keep things consistent). But is there something you can do about an edge case like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've not tried this but you might find a solution by looking at ember-data's source code, specifically states.js: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/states.js#L306-L351

Not sure there is a solid best practice here, but my best guess is that you can *recover* by sending `becameInvalid` to the model's stateManager.

Answer (score 6):

Building on [Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/983357/mike-grassotti) suggestion, I ended up with the following:

```
record.send('becameInvalid');
record.unloadRecord();
```